# Create an instance of subclass inside superclass

Tags: java, polymorphism, subclass, superclass

Whenever I create an instance of superclass, I want it to automatically create one instance of the subclass. Then I can access the subclass from an instance of the superclass.

Here I have a superclass name "SortArticles":

```java
public class SortArticles {
    private String title;
    private String linkToFullArticles;
    private FullArticle fullArticleObject;
    
    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }
    
    public FullArticle getFullArticleObject() {
        return this.fullArticleObject;
    } 
}
```

Here I have a subclass name "FullArticle":

```java
public class FullArticle extends SortArticles {
    
    private List<Label> labelList;

}
```

I want to call like this:

```java
ArrayList<SortArticles> sortList = new ArrayList<>();
sortList.add(new SortArticles());
sortList.get(0).getFullArticleObject().getTitle;
```

Is it possible to do that? I think of using HashMap to link sort and full, but I need create 2 arraylist, and link it manually.

Comment: Never do that. This is very Bad design.

Comment: No. You are not returning the instance of your child/sub class (`FullArticle`) with `this`, as `this` keyword is a reference to the *current* instance, which, in your case, is going to be the superclass (`SortArticles`).

Comment: So what is the solution. How can i link between the subclass and superclass? I just want all data that i add into an instance of superclass can be got through an instance of subclass

Comment: This question seems quite possibly an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) type question.  The solution is probably to improve your design from the get-go and not to link the subclass and superclass.

Comment: You can use an abstract class where getFullArticleObject there?

Answer (score 3):

You are misunderstanding the concept of inheritance.

You can say, that dog is an animal, but you can't know, that the animal, generally, barks, for sure.

It's children, who get properties of parents, not vice versa. When you instantiate some `SuperClass`, it's not instantiated along with its subclass(es) members, and it should *never* be.

For example, if you instantiate `java.lang.Object`, it should never (and it will never) have any members of your (let's say) `Employee` class; however, your `Employee` will always inherit all the non-private members of all its parents.

Besides, imagine you have hundred classes extending one `SuperClass`. Would you expect (or would you want, after all) the instance of your `SuperClass`, to contain all the non-private members of all hundred classes deriving from it? shall instance of `java.lang.Object` contain all the non-private infrastructure available on the class-path?

No, that's bad, that's wrong, that's not logical.